# Webdriver WebDriverException/TimeoutException on click

Tags: python, exception, selenium, click, webdriver

I'm using webdriver to click on a submit button on a form in an iframe. Basically:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name~='field_1']").clear()
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name~='field_1']").send_keys("123")
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name~='field_1']").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
self.driver.switch_to_window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])
self.assertEqual(self.driver.current_url, "http://fake_address.com")
```

I've also tried:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name~='field_1']").clear()
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name~='field_1']").send_keys("123")
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#submit-endslide").click()
self.driver.switch_to_window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])
self.assertEqual(self.driver.current_url, "http://fake_address.com")
```

and:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name~='field_1']").clear()
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name~='field_1']").send_keys("123")
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#submit-endslide").submit()
self.driver.switch_to_window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])
self.assertEqual(self.driver.current_url, "http://fake_address.com")
```

I've been getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_ytplayer_smoke_form.py", line 198, in testSmallFormSubmission
    self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name~='field_1']").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  File "/home/giant/our_player/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 293, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
  File "/home/giant/our_player/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 370, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/giant/our_player/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 166, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/giant/our_player/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message: u'Selenium took too long to run your command.
```

Then 
WebDriverException: Message: u'Due to a previous error, this job has already finished.

Regardless of which method I choose, I will always get a timeout when clicking the submit button;
(I've already tried increasing the timeout to 300)

Note:When I watch the test run, the submit button is being clicked and a new tab will open, but the test will never pass due to the exceptions.

Comment: Your traceback says that sending RETURN fails. You are not clicking on submit button but sending RETURN to input field in your 1st example. You Do in 2nd example - was the traceback the same? . Also, you may want to save located element in a variable to make your code easier to follow. Also, consider reading up on WebDriverWait and ExpectedConditions, they make Se2 much smoother to use.

Comment: The traceback is the same. If the issue was related to the wait, I would expect to see a NoSuchElementException; The submit button IS getting clicked and the popup is appearing, but I can never get to the assert as I get a timeoutException as I click the submit button(or hit RETURN)

Comment: This issue is specific to Chrome V28. I don't know why anyone would use an old browser, so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

There seemed to be a browser specific issue Chrome V28 that was causing this issue; I updated to the latest browser version Chrome V35 and this seemed to be resolved

Answer (score 0):

As my comment says, we need more info, but comments are ugly to edit, so I add more info here:

- Instead of wait based on time, try WebDriverWait see [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2012/07/12/how-to-webdriverwait/) for start.
- Store element in variable when found, like:

  field_1 = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name~='field_1']")
  field_1.clear()
  field_1.send_keys("123")
  submit = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#submit-endslide")
  submit.click()

But try to use WebElementDrive and ExpectedConditions instead of driver methods directly.